# how could we find the page URLs which is not linked to any menu in drupal 6?

Tags: php, drupal, menu, drupal-6

how could we find the page URLs which are not linked to any menu items or are stand-alone pages in drupal 6 ? any queries suggestion is also fine...

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM menu_links
WHERE link_path NOT 
IN (
  SELECT link_path
  FROM  `menu_links` 
  WHERE menu_name =  'navigation'
)
```